# Post para consulta dos dados da NF-e

Tags: post, get, nfe, jsoup

Estou tentando pegar os dados de uma nota fiscal eletrônica através de um post no site da fazenda. Estou usando a biblioteca JSoup.

Primeiro eu fiz um get para pegar a imagem do captcha e funcionou perfeitamente.
Criei minha tela com inputs para chave da nfe e para o catcha e quando submeto o form chamo a rotina post para pegar os dados da nota.

Só que nesse post só traz a pagina de erro, informando código do captcha inválido.

Segue o código do GET:

```
URL_GET = http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consulta.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8=
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL_GET).get();
String imgCaptcha = doc.select("#ContentPlaceHolder1_imgCaptcha").attr("src");
```

Segue o código do POST:

```
    URL_POST = http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consulta.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8%3d
doc = Jsoup.connect(URL_POST)
            .data("__EVENTTARGET", "")
            .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
            .data("__VIEWSTATE", dados.getViewState())
            .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", dados.getEventValidation())
            .data("ctl00$txtPalavraChave", "")
            .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtChaveAcessoCompleta", dados.getChaveAcesso())
            .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCaptcha", dados.getImgCaptcha())
            .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnConsultar", "Continuar")
            .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$token", dados.getToken())
            .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$captchaSom", dados.getCaptchaSom())
            .data("hiddenInputToUpdateATBuffer_CommonToolkitScripts", "1")
            .userAgent("Mozilla")
            .post();
```

Os dados (__VIEWSTATE e __EVENTVALIDATION) eu pego do GET e lanço no POST.
Os outros dados são default e a chave e o captcha recupero do que o usuário informou...

Alguém já fez algo parecido?

Comment: Chegou a verificar se no POST feito pelo site só tem esses parâmetros? E os cookies, inclusive o de sessão?

Comment: Pelo que vi estes são todos os parâmetros.
Não utilizei cookies!